# I am using addClass/removeClass and "data-" attribute to show/hide divs. How can I add next/previous?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to work out the template for an ebook. This is what I have at present: http://jsbin.com/otakab/2/edit  But the next/previous doesn't work.  Can you supply working code?

```
// Following function works
$(function() {
    $(".pageNumbers a").on("click", function(e) {
    //  Add highlight to the element clicked and remove highlighting from its siblings
    $(this).addClass("highlight").siblings().removeClass("highlight");
    //  Make use of our data attribute to show the correct page and hide the siblings
    $($(this).data('page')).show().siblings(".page").hide();                
});

//  Finally, dynamically click first page to start things off for the user 
//and provide proper highlighting and showing of text
  $("#a-1").click();

});

// Following function DOES NOT WORK
$(function() {
$(".direction a").on("click", function(e) {
// Trying to show the next/previous hidden div
$($(this).data('page')).show().siblings(".page").hide();

});

});
```

Comment: We need some HTML. What does `$(this).data('page')` return?

Comment: For html see http://jsbin.com/otakab/2/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your HTML, it looks like all you need to do is add `e.preventDefault()` to your `$('a').on('click',...)` code:

http://jsfiddle.net/juQCz/

```
$(".direction a").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $($(this).data('page')).show().siblings(".page").hide();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the jsfiddle. Nice.  There is one other function I couldn't figure out.  Can you get the highlighting of the page numbers at the top to change with next/previous.  It changes with the first function, but not with the next/previous function.

Comment: You just need to select the anchor with that `data-page` attribute: `$('.pageNumbers a[data-page="'+$(this).data('page')+'"]').addClass('highlight').siblings().removeClass('highlight');` -- http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/juQCz/2/